# Singleton on soap webservice client object in .net

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I am working on asp.net web application. I have question regarding soap webservice client instance in .net. What is best practice on creating an instance and how long should the instance live?
Should the instance be accessed from a singleton? Should the singleton be stored in the cache obejct HttpContext.Cache or a static variable? Can I reuse the same instance on every call? What is best practice?

Comment: It all depends on your specific requirements of your service.

Comment: Our web application has no database or any other storage. All calls goes to our backend via webservice calls. I am not sure what it should depend on. Do you mean depend on how many users?

Comment: So long as you don't store any request specific or user specific information in the singleton, you should be ok. Just be aware that if you app spans multiple servers, you will have multiple copies of the singleton.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your requirements? As @Maarten mentioned, it depends on your requirements.

Comment: My requirements are easy I want to do soap webservice calls with .net framework from my asp .net web application. What is the best way of managing the client instance when created? What more do you need to know? please specify what more you neeed to know.